# Error while converting JSON to Java Object

Tags: java, rest

I want to convert JSON to a java object. I created a class and I wrote code like this.I am getting exception `o/p:Unexpected character (c) at position 0`

I'm getting the JSON data from the client. but when I try to convert JSON to java I'm getting an error

```
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
        WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("my url");
        String name = "adn";
        String password = "12";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString
                .getBytes());
        // System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " +
        // authStringEnc);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                .get(ClientResponse.class);

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);




         output = output.substring(13, output.length() - 1);

            System.out.println(output);

         JSONParser parse = new JSONParser(); 



counts count=new counts();

         JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)parse.parse(output); 

         JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get("Counts"); 
        // System.out.println(jsonarr_1.get(1));

         JSONArray array = new JSONArray();


        //Get data for Results array

         for(int i=0;i<jsonarr_1.length();i++)

         {

         //Store the JSON objects in an array

         //Get the index of the JSON object and print the values as per the index

         JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject)jsonarr_1.get(i);


         System.out.println("Elements under results array");

         System.out.println("\nPlace id: " +jsonobj_1.get("college_name"));

         System.out.println("Types: " +jsonobj_1.get("college_epass_id"));

         }
```

I am getting the JSON data from client. I want to convert the JSON to java object. I created `pojo(counts)` class also. The json data is like this:

> o/p:college_name":"GPT n,
>   Kakda","college_epass_id":128},{"college_name":"GT,
>   am","college_epass_id":2946}

error:

> Unexpected character (c) at position 0.

Comment: It seems to me that your JSON doesn't have a valid structure. (I did not take a look at your code)

Comment: {i removed the line( output = output.substring(13, output.length() - 1);).,,,,i am getting another exception o/p:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 2):

---

**Use of Jackson**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
```

Your classes will be some like

```
public class CollegeList{
  @JsonProperty("counts")
  public List<College> counts;
}



 public class College{
     @JsonProperty("college_name") public String college_name;
     @JsonProperty("college_epass_id") public int college_epass_id;
    }
```

You can convert the json into respective object by

```
CollegeList colleges = mapper.readValue(jsonString, CollegeList .class);
```

Sharing [Reference](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) Link for more details.

Comment: its showing o/p like this o/p:::::Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Comment: Typically problems like this are due to incompatible versions: make sure that all your Jackson components have same minor version. So if you are using Jackson 2.9 then all libraries related to Jackson should be of 2.9 version.

Comment: can you provide jars of jackson any one version.i cant find jars for same version.

Comment: Download from below shared location depending on version required .http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjacksonall190jar.htm

Comment: i downloaded jars rohan.i am getting another error o/p:Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: The problem may happen when you're trying to read a list with a single element as a JsonArray rather than a JSONObject or vice versa. So do check your JSON data and Code once. Your array cannot be deserialized as object niether object can be deserailized as array.

Comment: POST your JSON data here... So I will send you exact conversion of it ,if required.

Comment: {"counts":[{"college_name":"GT for mn, Kaada","college_id":128},{"college_name":"GT for wmn, Drakamam","college_id":296},{"college_name":"GT for minorities, Anaparthi","college_id":2936},{"college_name":"GT for hostel, Pitharam","college_id":242}]}

Comment: i sent my json data in above comment .check once rohan.

Comment: Welcome Siva !! Mark the answer as Accepted !!

Comment: i have a doubt rohan .how can i store object into hashmap .and iterate the keys values. beacuse iam storing the java data into object                            CollegeList colleges = mapper.readValue(output, CollegeList.class);

  System.out.println(colleges);

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are truncating the response on this line...

```
 output = output.substring(13, output.length() - 1);
```

This will make the JSON string invalid

Perhaps you should consider removing this line of code or creating a separate variable to store the substring.

Comment: Hi head, i tried that way . iam getting another exception :o/p:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Comment: looks like you've imported the wrong JSONObject class.  Do you have a line like 

"import org.json.JSONObject"

at the top of your class? If so change it to "import org.json.simple.JSONObject"

Comment: ya head, i have that import name in my class

Comment: does changing the import fix your issue?

Comment: hi head, iam getting another exception o/p:Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: can you please provide the contents of the output variable?

Comment: {"counts":[{"college_name":"GT for mn, Kaada","college_id":128},{"college_name":"GT for wmn, Drakamam","college_id":296},{"college_name":"GT for minorities, Anaparthi","college_id":2936},{"college_name":"GT for hostel, Pitharam","college_id":242}]}

Comment: i sent my json data in above comment

Comment: This code works for me...

  JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();

  JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)parse.parse(output);

  JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get("counts");

  for (Object arrayEntry : jsonarr_1) {
   JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject)arrayEntry;
   System.out.println("\nPlace id: " +jsonobj_1.get("college_name"));
   System.out.println("Types: " +jsonobj_1.get("college_id"));
  }

Comment: i tried in another way .i am getting the java object data.thank you for ur suggestions head

Comment: how can i store object into hashmap .and iterate the keys values. beacuse iam storing the java data into object                                               
         CollegeList colleges = mapper.readValue(output, CollegeList.class); System.out.println(colleges);    // i am storing the java object values into "colleges" .how i store into hashmap and iterate ..